# How to unlink multiple files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to unlink all file with name from the database: [file name in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVe11.png).
I try to use code like this but it doesn't work:

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
     $infokeg = Infokeg::where('id', $id)->first();
     $image[] = $infokeg->foto_kegiatan
     unlink(public_path("data_file/".json_decode($image)));
     $infokeg->delete();
     return redirect('infokeg')->with('msg', 'Data Telah Terhapus');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`File::delete()` will handle the array of files to be deleted for you,

At first, add it `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

```
public function destroy($id)
{
 $infokeg = Infokeg::where('id', $id)->first();
 $image[] = $infokeg->foto_kegiatan  
 // pass the array of files to deleted to it. 
 // if $image array is like this $image = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.png'];
 File::delete($image);
 
 return redirect('infokeg')->with('msg', 'Data Telah Terhapus');
}
```

#### Method 2

At first add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

```
public function destroy($id)
{
 $infokeg = Infokeg::where('id', $id)->first();
 $image[] = $infokeg->foto_kegiatan  
 // pass the array of files to deleted to it. 
 // if $image array is like this $image = ['file.jpg', 'file2.jpg'];
 Storage::delete($image);
 
 return redirect('infokeg')->with('msg', 'Data Telah Terhapus');
}
```

For method 2 refer from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#deleting-files)

---

EDIT:

append public path to all,

```
foreach ($image as &$value) {
   $value = public_path("data_file/".$value);
}
```

It will append the public path to all the values in the array, then use it in the delete() method as its argument.

Comment: this method just delete data form database, but image on public still there

Comment: no, both the methods will delete from public folder as well as well, check your path

Comment: i have path like this : public/data_file/myfile, so what must i modif to detect data_file path ?

Answer (score 0):

using for to delete it

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       $infokeg = Infokeg::where('id', $id)->first();
       $image = json_decode($infokeg->foto_kegiatan);
       $length = count($image);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
           unlink(public_path("data_file/".$image[$i]));
       }
       $infokeg->delete();
       return redirect('infokeg')->with('msg', 'Data Telah Terhapus');
   }
```